# How to remotely edit a line containing double quotes and variables using sed across ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, sed, sh

I have a `sed` command that works perfectly if I run it locally on Ubuntu or our embedded client Arago:

```
sed -i 's/export PART="$1"/export PART="A"/' flash.sh
```

This results in exactly what I need on both versions of `sed`, a line that changes:

```
export PART="$1"
```

to

```
export PART="A"
```

My problem is, I need to run that same command across a network to the embedded client so I tried this on an Ubuntu server using bash, to an Arago client using sh:

```
ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@10.14.150.113 sed -i 's/PART="$1"/PART="A"/' flash.sh
```

Which results in a line that contains:

```
export PART=A"$1"
```

The substitution command needs to stay inside the single quotes so the double quotes are passed as literals, or maybe there's a better way to keep the double quotes in the two strings?  This looks to me like the `$1` is simply being ignored like it's empty and the `"A"` is being passed as `A` and replacing the end of `PART=`.  I've tried encapsulating the command in single and double quotes, which both result in the same thing.  I've also tried escaping the quotes with backslashes, same result.  I think this is something with quote expansion with sh that I simply don't understand.  Or possibly something I don't understand with ssh.

I've read through a number of other threads that are similar, but none of them dealt with using ssh to run the command remotely.  I'm no longer a novice at sed, but this one has become quite the puzzle for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@10.14.150.113 'sed -i "s/export PART=\"\\\$1\"/export PART=\"A\"/" flash.sh'
```

Comment: This method works perfectly!  Thanks Dimitre!  I was close to this solution at one point, but didn't know about using triple backslashes to escape the $ character.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back and forth to get the quoting you need. try this

```
ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@10.14.150.113 sed -i 's/PART='"$1"'/PART="A"/' flash.sh
# -------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

OR if you really need the value of $1 surrounded by dbl-quotes,

```
ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@10.14.150.113 sed -i 's/PART='\"$1\"'/PART="A"/' flash.sh
# -------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

You do want $1 to come from your local machine (not the ssh'd to machine), right?

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Hi @shellter, I believe he don't want to expand $1 at all.

Comment: Hi @DimitreRadoulov : yes,  you're probably right. I took the sentence (fragment) "This looks to me like the $1 is simply being ignored like it's empty" to mean that he *did* want to pass in a value for $1, but now I can see it is probably meant to be a string literal. Oh well. Good luck to all! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried both methods above, and both result in the same problem I was having before:

   export PART=A"$1"

And you're correct, I need the files to have a quoted variable:  "$1".  I'm going to try the next solution below, and I'll report back.  Thanks again.